# sed edit, delete xml tags

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I'm newbie with great editor called - sed.

I want to delete all the xml tags and extract string between specific tag - reportBody

Here how is it looks like in a single line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><SOAP- ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="blablah"><SOAP-ENV:Body> <getReportResponsexmlns:msgns="blahblahblah" xmlns="blahblah"><returnxmlns=""> <returnCode><majorReturnCode>000</majorReturnCode><minorReturnCode>0000</minorReturnCode><returnCode><reportName>blahblah</reportName><reportTitle>blahblahblahr</reportTitle><reportBody>STRING TO EXTRACT</reportBody><reportMimeType>text/csv</reportMimeType></return></getReportResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The problem is that xml file CAN be different, sometimes it's written in a single line either written in 2-3 lines or the string to extract will be stored on more than 1 line between reportBody tag. so it can be something like that or even different:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?><SOAP- ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="blablah"><SOAP-ENV:Body> 
`enter code here`<getReportResponsexmlns:msgns="blahblahblah" xmlns="blahblah">
<returnxmlns=""> <returnCode>
<majorReturnCode>000</majorReturnCode><minorReturnCode>0000</minorReturnCode>
<returnCode>
<reportName>blahblah</reportName><reportTitle>blahblahblahr</reportTitle><reportBody>
STRING 
TO 
EXTRACT</reportBody>
<reportMimeType>text/csv</reportMimeType></return>
</getReportResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What is the solution to deal with all the possible changes? 
Also, can I set parameters to save files and decode string to base64? Thanks !

Comment: Good idea, but this string can contain more symbols than the max. value of string, so xml parser couldn't handle it.

Comment: It's a shame that the XML in your question isn't valid - I suspect that this is just a result of you preparing an example for us. If it's valid, then as @123 has suggested, you should really use a command like `xmllint --xpath '//reportBody/text()' file.xml`.

Comment: it's not valid :( it comes from a m2m server with attached base64 encoded file inside reportBody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this gnu-awk to extract it:

```
awk -v RS='<reportBody>.*</reportBody>' 'RT{print RT}' file.xml
<reportBody>
STRING
TO
EXTRACT</reportBody>
```

With first input you will get this output:

```
<reportBody>STRING TO EXTRACT</reportBody>
```

`-v RS='<reportBody>.*</reportBody>'` will set input record separator as any text from `<reportBody>` to `</reportBody>`

Use:

```
awk -v RS='<reportBody>.*</reportBody>' 'RT{
     gsub(/<\/?reportBody>[[:space:]]*/, "", RT); print RT}' file.xml
```

If you want to extract string inside the tags.

Comment: Updated : Saw you old message, thanks a million! 

Old: So, awk can easily extract string (STRING TO EXTRACT) between "reportBody" tags? does it matter that string can be stored on more than 1 line or exactly in 1 line? Also the whole xml won't be the same as you can see "reportName" and "reportTitle" tags, the string between them won't be the same.

Comment: Amazing, will try it with full file (more than 10k symbols), Thank you again!

Comment: doesn't work :( output file is empty, maybe I did something wrong

Comment: found a solution with sed
Works with any cases 
------ cat $1 | tr "\n" "|" | grep -o '<reportBody>.*</reportBody>' | sed 's/\(<reportBody>\|<\/reportBody>\)//g' | sed 's/|/\n/g' | sed '/^\s*$/d' > $2

Comment: Hmm that's really an awfully inefficient solution as theoretically input may contain `pipe` character and due to so many piped command it will be very slow for bigger files

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s8ThSTX0     
Yep, I know :)) but only this one work out with many different entities

Comment: Wow, could you please send me your script file? I was right that I did something wrong

Comment: It is the same awk command I showed in answer above i.e. **`awk -v RS='<reportBody>.*</reportBody>' 'RT{gsub(/<\/?reportBody>[[:space:]]*/, "", RT); print RT}' file.xml`**

Comment: Works! Thank you very much for this code. Can I add to this code  -> base64 -d filename  <- to decode it to base64?

Comment: Yes `awk -v RS='<reportBody>.*</reportBody>' 'RT{gsub(/<\/?reportBody>[[:space:]]*/, "", RT); print RT}' file.xml | ase64 -d`

Comment: Attached whole code, everything is nice, thank you again ! :)